# Маппинг данных в модель

Tags: golang, orm, gorm

Можно ли как-нибудь в [gorm](https://gorm.io/) передать интерфейс, который является моделью данных (структурой) в `Find`. Пример:

```
func MyFunc(results interface{}) error {
    // anything actions
    err := c.db.Raw(query, valuesWhere...).Find(&results).Error
    // anything actions
}
```

Вызов:

```
var p []*Project 
MyFunc(p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение такое:

```
func MyFunc(results interface{}) error {
    // anything actions
    err := c.db.Raw(query, valuesWhere...).Find(results).Error
    // anything actions
}
```

Вызов:

```
var p []Project 
MyFunc(&p)
```

[Ответ](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/4163) на github.

[Ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66547710/mapping-interface-to-struct/66547872#66547872) на SO.en.